# Access host disk from Windows 7 Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

This seems like a simple task, but I need to copy files from my host machine to my virtual PC. I am running Windows 7 Virtual PC.

I usually use \tsclient, but that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the drive and map it...

Comment: from within the guest OS?

Comment: ok, from the host OS, I was able to access it by typing this in windows explorer: \\mossbasedev\d$

Comment: yea the integration feature should work, but sharing always works.